# How to add the another data below existing data in JSON response in Flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

```
"joint_user_detail_list": {
      "joint_user1": {
        "ihl_user_id": "lK6dlQ2NU0WNKXk5lx07Lg",
        "ihl_user_name": "Guest User",
        "status": "requested",
        "vital_read": true,
        "vital_write": true,
        "teleconsult_read": true,
        "teleconsult_write": true
      }
    }
```

This is the response of body from one api! I have to add another joint user 2 below this array upto 15 joint users
How to do? please help

Comment: Change it from `Map` to `List`, like `"joint_user_detail_list": [{ "joint_user1": { "ihl_user_id": "lK6dlQ2NU0WNKXk5lx07Lg", "ihl_user_name": "Guest User", "status": "requested", "vital_read": true, "vital_write": true, "teleconsult_read": true, "teleconsult_write": true } }]`

Answer (score 0):

If the response body is json string you need convert it into Map Variable(ignore this step if it's already Map Variable):

```
Map<String,dynamic> jsonMap = JsonDecode(body);
```

Then just modify it like below:

```
jsonMap["joint_user_detail_list"]["joint_user2"] =
 {
        "ihl_user_id": "any data",
        "ihl_user_name": "any data",
        "status": "any data",
        "vital_read": true,
        "vital_write": true,
        "teleconsult_read": true,
        "teleconsult_write": true
      };
```